# calculate FWHM in python

Tags: python

in this graph how can I calculate FWHM?

```
x = [1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,15,10,14,13,12,11,14,10,8,7,2]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
```

please help.

Comment: explain to us what is FWHM and what have you done so far

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FWHM calculation using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49100778/fwhm-calculation-using-python)